# Knime MongoDBReader read an Object with an array in it

Tags: knime

I tried to read an Object with the MongoDB reader and I always get the following error message:

> "ERROR MongoDB Reader       0:19       Execute failed: Invalid type 19 for field value".

The typ of the field value is an Array.
I want to read the object and want to get the array inside the Object.

Here you can see the MongoDB with the Object I want to read.

[image: MongoDB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Type 19” indicates a `Decimal128` type, see [this link](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/).

I’d assume that this type is just not supported by the MongoDB nodes (note how above link says “New in version 3.4.”).

[personal opinion] The KNIME MongoDB nodes are not very well maintained. Beside some basic “hello world” attempts I wasn’t able to use them for any of my real-world usage scenarios.